# Pass data between 2 activities using viewModel and livedata

Tags: android, android-activity, viewmodel, android-livedata

Is it possible to pass data between activities by using viewModel class?

I have tried to update Model object from one Activity and another Activity, and observe changes on the second activity, but it did not help. I don't want to use Bundle, if possible using viewModel.

Comment: Be aware that if you don't use Bundle, then Activity2 can easily end up with uninitialized value after low memory condition - because your app restarts with Activity2 being the first activity to ever run.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, so there's no way for this via viewModel?

Comment: ViewModels belong to the "non-config instance scope of an Activity", therefore the only way to do that would be a shared singleton (which need to be persisted via `BaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState`). Activities are fairly limited in this way, that's why I personally favor single-Activity solutions.

Comment: okay, so sticking with Bundles for now.